# How can I get the video time being miliseconds

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using the  WMPLib in C# and I want to get video time in milliseconds.I will configure another program by using these milliseconds values.Is there any way to get VMP data in milliseconds?
Also I tried :

```
double temp = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest what you can get is the [`currentPositionTimecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property, which along with current position in time gives you a frame number. Knowing the frame rate will let you approximate the position in milliseconds:

```
var frameRateMs = frameRate/1000;

var positionMs = currentFrameNumber/frameRateMs
```

Comment: I tried write axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.CurrentPositionTimeCode but compiler not like this.Do you have any idea?

Comment: @dodotu it's lower case "c" in "Timecode" and in "current". Compiler should've presented you a clear error message, not "I don't like this" message.

Comment: I know but when I pressed ctrl+space after Controls, currentPositionTimecode is not shown.Actually my problem was that.

Comment: @dodotu Sorry, I don't understand. If your problem was other than what you've stated in your question why didn't you ask about it? SO is about concrete answers to concrete problems. I suggest deleting this question if this thread is not helpful (if it is, consider accepting this answer) and **ask another question** in a new, different post, where you should **clearly** describe what **is** your problem **exactly** :-)

Comment: You have to use the [proper interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You know, sorry, but that's so obvious that I can't help having an impression that either you stated your question in a wrong way, or you have missed some huge things out there.

Like, basic math.

`currentPosition` is provided in **seconds** and it's a `double` so it **has fractions**. To get it in milliseconds, **simply multiply that by 1000**.

```
// get your player from UI
AxWindowsMediaPlayer player1 = .....;

// not even a cast is needed
double millis = player1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition * 1000;
```

So, to get the position in milliseconds you **don't need** anything except the basic AxWMP interfaces.

If you really want to get that as Text or Timecode, they can be fetched too, but a cast will be needed to work on correct interface (since AxWindowsMediaPlayer uses IWMPControls by default and IWMPControls2/3 are needed for that):

```
string text = ((IWMPControls2)player1.Ctlcontrols).currentPositionString;
string text2 = ((IWMPControls2)player1.Ctlcontrols).currentPositionTimecode;
```